# jQuery this and class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a display of portfolio items and when I click I want the object to appear, the portfolio code is as below -- the div .info is set to display:none as default.

```
<div class="portfolio-item tango">
                <div class="info">portfolio info</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item truvoz">
                <div class="info">portfolio info</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item tt">
                <div class="info">portfolio info</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item sow">
                <div class="info">portfolio info</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item ih">
                <div class="info">portfolio info</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item jmm">
                <div class="info">portfolio info</div>
            </div>
```

When I use the code snippet to test on the first item it works fine -

```
$(".tango").click(function() { $(".tango .info").toggle("fast"); });
```

However I would like to make it so for example it works in this sort of fashion

```
$(".portfolio-item").click(function() { $("this .info").toggle("fast"); });
```

This way its just this one line of code to work for all cases...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(selector, context)`:

```
$(".portfolio-item").click(function() { 
    $(".info", this).toggle("fast"); 
});
```

or `find` method:

```
$(".portfolio-item").click(function() { 
    $(this).find(".info").toggle("fast"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".portfolio-item").click(function() { $(".info",this).toggle("fast"); });
```